# I want to create one time activity

Tags: android

I want to create one time activity window to my Android app.
In the window have two buttons.the buttons are connect to two different pages.
If you download app and run for the first time, you see this window first.then you have to select one button.

When you click the button, you will connect to the target page.
If you close the app, and open it again you can't see the window with two buttons.
The only thing you can see, the window that you previously selected with the button.

This is the thing, I want to do.
I tryied many codes based on YouTube videos.
But I didn't get the progress, that I want.

This the demo app for my course project.
I stuck with this problem.

you can download my project :-

Dropbox - https://www.dropbox.com/s/r4iztx8onqu2ctz/demo.zip?dl=0

Zippyshare - https://www85.zippyshare.com/v/bnXekEoz/file.html

Comment: Can you maybe provide some code samples from your implementation attempt?

Comment: @GregorKoukkoullis you can download my project

Dropbox - https://www.dropbox.com/s/r4iztx8onqu2ctz/demo.zip?dl=0

Zippyshare - https://www85.zippyshare.com/v/bnXekEoz/file.html

Answer (score 1):

You can save a bit in SharedPrefrence "isFirstRun" set it to true when the application is first run and go through your first activity.. for future run you can check if the "isFirstRun" bit is true skip the first activity.

More about SharedPrefrences here.. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

Answer (score 1):

In your **MainActivity** :

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
    boolean firstRun = settings.getBoolean("firstRun", true);
    if (firstRun) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IntroActivity.class));
    }
```

Create new  Activity and named **IntroActivity**,and in `Onclick` Button :

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("firstRun", false);
                editor.apply();
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could also do is use install referer receiver then store the value in shared preferences and use that once you open activity https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/InstallReferrerReceiver